# GoMage LightCheckout doesn't work

Tags: php, magento, gomage

We inherited magento based shop with GoMage LightCheckout extension (http://www.gomage.com/extensions/gomage-lightcheckout.html) installed.
For some reason this extensions doesn't work. In other words, this extension is active and properly installed but we still see default checkout instead of Gomage lightcheckout.

I found that some people reported problems with gomage extension if https/http, www in domains names used.

Cache had been cleared, compilation  turned off. We tried to re-install extension, but that did not help us.

Comment: That's pretty vague. What exactly doesn't work? Do you receive any errors? Are you using the default magento theme to rule out theme issues?

Comment: Borderline programming related -- this probably belongs over in http://magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: yes, that sounds strange. But that is what we have. Customer says that it worked before, but suddenly stopped. I was also told that it did not work with 'www' in domain